# Simple negation of statement on graph theory

Tags: logic, graph-theory

I am trying to negate the following statement but my logic is alittle rusty...

Statment: There exists a set $X \subset V (G) -
\{u, v\}$ such that some vertex in X is adjacent to
both u and v.

My terrible Attempt: For all set's $X \subset V (G) $ then for all $x \in X $ x is adjacent to u or v?

Please give me a hint not the full answer and ill try and fix it.

Edit: For all set's $X \subset V (G)-
\{u, v\} $ then for all $x \in X $ x is not adjacent to both u and v?

Comment: Your original statement isn't that clear, either. Perhaps "There exists a subset $X\subset V(G)$  such that for all pairs $u,v\in V(G)$ there exists some $x\in X$ that is adjacent to both $u$ and $v$"

Comment: That was my original concern but i believe it was originally stated in this way for me to realize just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- The negation of "there exists $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$" is "for all $x$ we have $\neg \varphi(x)$".
- The negation of "$p$ and $q$" is "$\neg p$ or $\neg q$".